# Sod not getting enough water?

Tags: watering, grass, soil-amendment, sod

I had sod installed about 12 days ago and its taking really well in 95% of the yard, nice and green and is taking root. There are a few sprinklers near the back brick wall that are not far enough back and don't provide enough water to the surrounding grass. I have been manually watering these areas since the installation when I noticed it wasn't getting enough water.

Aside from the continual water, is there any amendments I can apply to those patches or the dirt underneath them? I can pick the back sections up as if they were just laid on top, they haven't taken root in the browned areas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Grass is a waste of space unless you're having it for your kids. put some raised beds in, and let them play at the neighbors..

Comment: The yard / amount of grass was solely based around the kids, giving them as much room as possible for running around, as well as our dogs.

Comment: The way you phrased your question makes it sound like you paid someone to install it. Call them up and have them come look at it and give you advice. Would be helpful to know what type of sod was used. Some types of grass go dormant without enough water. Others just die. For such a small area I would just cut it out and lay new sod. Make sure it stays moist until the roots take hold. Depending on your sprinkler layout and types of sprinklers you may just be able to adjust the arc of some heads if the system was designed with proper head to head coverage.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing you could do is simply get a little longer hose or invest in a sprinkler that has a higher pressure to water bigger areas at a time. You could also go and water the little bit manually, if that is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I don't mind the manual watering for the time being. I wanted to wait until it all took root and some time to grow before i start moving some sprinkler heads around.  You don't think its too far gone where it wouldn't come back at this point, even with the watering? Just not sure if i need to replace those pieces since they are dying and haven't taken root yet.

Comment: By the looks of the pictures they look very much savable. Give them some water and sees what happens. I think they will come back for you.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to cut out those severely browned areas and fit new sod in. Try to get the sod from the same grower, if possible, to match. Make sure the soil in the problem areas is highly amended with rich humous and peat prior to resoding. Those red bricks sure can heat up and I believe that's a lot of the problem in those areas. Water, water, water. Consider a soaker hose to run along the bricks until the grass is fully established.